# Remove borders on custom Entry & Editor for Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working with a UWP project in Xamarin Forms.

When i use the default Entry & Editor, it comes with a border that i wish to remove as well as add a rounded background.

I have setup the renderer and some code, but the border is still intact.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Entry), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace App1.UWP
{
class MyRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control != null)
        {
            Control.Background = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can set BorderThickness = "0" and TextControlBorderBrush to `Transparent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Entry

Simply set `BorderThickness` in custom renderer .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Entry), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace App1.UWP
{
    class MyRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control != null)
            {   
                Control.BorderThickness = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Editor :

It's weird that EditorRenderer of `Editor` does not work (OnElementChanged not trigger) , we have to subclass `Editor` and create custom renderer for the new class .

Forms

```
public class MyEditor : Editor
{

}


//xaml

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
<local:MyEditor/>
```

Custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEditor), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace App1.UWP
{
    class MyRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderThickness = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```